# Two conditions equivalent to continuity of function between topological spaces

Tags: general-topology

If $X$ is a topological space, we denote by $\mathcal{F}(X)$ the set of all closed sets of the space $X$, and for every $A\subseteq X$ denote by $A^{\,\text{--}}$ the closure of the subset $A$ in the space $X$.

> Let $f\colon X\to Y$ be a function between topological spaces. The following
>   are equivalent:
>
> $\quad(1)\:$ $f(A^{\,\text{--}}) \subseteq f(A)^{\,\text{--}}$ for every
>   $A\subseteq X\,$;
>   $\quad(2)\:$ for every $F\in\mathcal{F}(Y)$ the inverse image $f^{-1}(F)$
>   is in $\mathcal{F}(X)\,$;
>   $\quad(3)\:$ if $A,B\subseteq X$ are such that
>   $A^{\,\text{--}}=B^{\,\text{--}}$,
>   then $f(A)^{\,\text{--}}=f(B)^{\,\text{--}}$;
>   $\quad(4)\:$ if $A,B\subseteq X$ are such that
>   $A^{\,\text{--}}\subseteq B^{\,\text{--}}$,
>   then $f(A)^{\,\text{--}}\subseteq f(B)^{\,\text{--}}$.

All four conditions are of course equivalent to continuity of the function $f$.
However, while the conditions $(1)$ and $(2)$
    are staple fodder of undergraduate courses of topology,
I have yet to see either one of the conditions $(3)$ and $(4)$ in mathematical literature,
either spelled out in the text or offered as an exercise.
Did anybody come across any of these two conditions, perhaps in some disguise, somewhere, anywhere?

Comment: typing \bar{A} results in $\bar{A}$

Comment: @Evargalo I know that, but I do not like overlines over expressions: I prefer $(A\cup B\cup C)^{\,\text{--}}$ to $\overline{A\cup B\cup C}$. Also, when closures alternate with interiors, as in $A^{\,\text{--}\,\circ\,\text{--}}$, the overlines and circles would pile one atop the other.

Comment: Ok then. Btw, it is not worthy of an answer, but I've never met those two conditions - or I've forgotten about it.

Comment: If not in math literature, where did you see them?

Comment: about notation... why do you use $A^{\,\text{--}\,\circ\,\text{--}}$ instead of simply ${A^{-\,\circ\, -}} $?

Comment: @trying I discovered them as four equivalent properties of Galois connections between two posets equipped with closure operators; such Galois connections are then generalizations of continuous maps in topology, and they pop up in many places outside topology. When I formulated the four conditions for topological spaces I noticed that two of the conditions I have never met before, in topology or anywhere else. When applied in logic, the relation $A^{\,\text{--}}\subseteq B^{\,\text{--}}$ turns out to be entailment -- $B$ entails $A$.

Comment: @trying "About notation" Here it does not look much different, but in the proper LaTeX-typeset text, "$-$" is longer and thinner than "$\text{--}$"; the latter is even not properly typeset in these pages (text is not LaTeXed, not even in math mode).

Comment: I have occasionally seen $A^-$ in print for $\bar A$, for the same reason of "superscripts piling up". For example in  a proof of a result of Kuratowski, that, starting with any $A,$ repeated iterations of Closure and Complement  (in any order) will produce at most $14$ sets (including $A$). The key is that $f(f(A))=f(A)$ and $g(A)=g(g(A))$ where $f(A)=Int(Cl(A))=A^{-c-c}$ and $g(A)=Cl(Int(A))=A^{c-c-}.$ (The superscripts are evaluated from L to R with $B^-=\bar B$, and $B^c$  is the complement of $B.$)

Answer (score 0):

In the context of metric spaces, condition (3) is  like the condition that $(f(x_n))_n$ converges to $f(x)$ whenever $(x_n)_n$ converges to $x$.

Comment: Not quite: this is a consequence of condition (1).